# Sort a list without built functions like sort,set,min,max,remove in python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a two dimensional list that I have to sort and I have to only use while loops. So far my code does not work for all lists.

```
def sort(list):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < len(list):
        while j < len(list[i]) - 1:
            if list[i][j] > list[i][j + 1]:
                temp = list[i][j]
                list[i][j] = list[i][j + 1]
                list[i][j + 1] = temp
            j += 1
        j = 0
        i += 1
    return list
sort([[3,5,2,8,6,9],[9,1,2,5]])
```

This code still has numbers out of order. Is there a better way to sort?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.
Specifically, what did you get, and what do you expect?  This code appears to sort each list independently.

Comment: http://python3.codes/popular-sorting-algorithms/

Answer (score 2):

Your inner loop takes only one pass through the list.  This guarantees that the largest element is at the end, but doesn't necessarily do anythign else.  You need to add a loop to continue while you still have unfinished business.

I left in the tracing statements I used to highlight the problem, as well as the simple reverse-order case.

```
def sort(list):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < len(list):
        done = False
        while not done:
            done = True
            while j < len(list[i]) - 1:
                print i, j, list[i][j], list[i][j + 1]
                if list[i][j] > list[i][j + 1]:
                    temp = list[i][j]
                    list[i][j] = list[i][j + 1]
                    list[i][j + 1] = temp
                    done = False
                    print "SWAP", list[i]
                j += 1

            j = 0

        i += 1
    return list

print sort([[6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]])
print sort([[3,5,2,8,6,9],[9,1,2,5]])
```